# Android Emoticons to HTML format

Tags: php, android, html, emoticons

We are working on 1 Application where we have to create functionality from where user can enter emoticons from android keyboard using App and we has to send this emoticons through Email in HTML format, Is there any solution where we can see Android emoticons as it displayed on android in HTML ?

Comment: [refer this link](https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji)